# How do I get multiple view models to see a change in a boolean variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My WPF C# application is a stats tracking application for basketball. Here is the [Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvpnw.png) of the application.

The user will select the home and opposing teams and click the New Game button. This is in a separate view model called Menu_VM.

When the New Game button is clicked, I would like the list box on the left-hand side to propagate with the players on the home team. The list box is in the main view model called Main_VM.

When a command is called from clicking the New Game button, I would like a boolean variable to be set to true. This way I can use this throughout my many view models to tell if a game is in session.

My question is how I would go about handling the change event for the bool, so that it will allow other view models to see this change.

I'm looking for a general solution that I can utilize throughout the other view models.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: You didn't post any code, so you'll have to take this solution and match it to the way you have implemented things.*

In the "main" viewmodel where you define your bool, write an event handler on the PropertyChanged event, then this will allow other view models to react to its change.

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += OnViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    private bool gameInSession;
    private ChildViewModel childViewModel;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool GameInSession 
    { 
        get => gameInSession; 
        set { gameInSession = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GameInSession")); }
    }
    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.childViewModel == null)
                this.childViewModel = new ChildViewModel(this);
            return this.childViewModel;
        }
    }

    private void OnViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(GameInSession))
        {
            // Update other view models whenever this flag changes
            this.ChildViewModel.Update(GameInSession);
        }
    }
}
```